# Is there a way to automatically improve the quality of pictures taken with the camera?

Tags: camera, photos

Is there a way to automatically improve the quality of pictures taken with the camera? For example with some sort of post-processing

I was told that iPhone makes better photos because of good (built-in) post-processing software (which runs automatically). Can I have the same on Android somehow?

Comment: Opinionated questions such as app recommendations are not very welcome here. If you are looking to do something specific, then you can modify your question on how to do something. Don't just ask for an app that can edit photos.

Comment: Also, please do not "sign" your questions or add "thanks". It's just noise that detracts from the content. Please see [ask].

Comment: "Best" and "good" are still subjective criteria. Stack Exchange works best for questions that have (the potential for) a single, correct answer.

Comment: I think you missed the point why your question was closed that was [explained in the close message](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). I've edited your question so that it becomes on-topic again.

Comment: Are you rooted? If so, you could try flashing other camera apk's to see if they make a difference. For instance, I have a Samsung Galaxy S3, but instead of using the default Samsung camera, I have flashed the Google 4.2.2 JB Camera. I don't really know how different the image quality is, but the layout is definitely different. Something like this might also help you.

Answer (score 1):

The new updates to Google+ has features called auto enhance auto awesome. It is a feature that automatically enhances the photos you have uploaded.  Just make sure instant upload is on and the auto enhance settings are on in the app Settings>Camera&photos.  Here are the things that it does. https://support.google.com/plus/answer/3113884?hl=en